# Microdata – Making a review article

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I was just wondering if someone could help me with some microdata. This is what I'm working with:

> I'm making a site where they review other sites. So a review is an article. Each review/article contains a name and text and also ratings. There's two ratings, one that the site/author made and one by the visitors. The rating is between 1-10.

This is what I've done so far (I'm using schema.org):

The body is a [WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage). Then I have a content area that is a [Review](http://schema.org/Review). The review contains a name/title and the review itself (reviewBody).

Then I have the ratings. I said that there's the author rating and the visitor rating. So I've made those as a [AggregateRating](http://schema.org/AggregateRating). Like this:

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
    <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="10">
    <strong itemprop="ratingValue">8.33</strong>
    <span>by "the site"</span>
</div>
```

So my question is: Is this the right thing to do? Is this even an actual rating? How would you do it?

Also, when checking my example page with [Google's structured data tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) the data is defined as I was expecting but I don't get the nice looking rich snippet, the one with the stars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `revewCount` property of the aggregateRating.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
    <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="10">
    <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="20">
    <strong itemprop="ratingValue">8.33</strong>
    <span>by "the site"</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This markup should work fine. Checked it with the Google's [structured data tool.](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=&html=%3Cdiv%20itemscope%20itemtype=%22http://schema.org/WebPage%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20itemprop=%22aggregateRating%22%20itemscope%20itemtype=%22http://schema.org/AggregateRating%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20itemprop=%22worstRating%22%20content=%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20itemprop=%22bestRating%22%20content=%2210%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20itemprop=%22reviewCount%22%20content=%2220%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstrong%20itemprop=%22ratingValue%22%3E8.33%3C/strong%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%3Eby%20%22the%20site%22%3C/span%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C/div%3E%0D%0A%3C/div%3E)

Comment: Thanks that worked very well. Found another problem too, the __aggregateRating__ cannot be inside the __review__, they need to be separate. Did not know that.

Comment: Forgot to give you the bounty, sorry, you should have it now :)